# Condition on $X$ so that $X^TX$ is positive definite

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, positive-definite

If I have $X_{n \times {m}}$ matrix, where:

- $n \ne m$ in general case
- $\mathsf {rk}(X)=max(n,m)$

how can I define $X$ so that the $X^TX$ is positive definite (all eigenvalues positive). This covariance matrix should be $m \times m$.

In other words what should be condition for $X$ so that covariance matrix $X^TX$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition is that the rank be equal to $m.$

Comment: Is this equivalent that $X$  has no zero singular values? I need condition for $X$ so that ...

Comment: Aha you meant rank of $X$ should be $m$? Right ?

Comment: If the matrix is of full rank (as supposed in the question, $\mbox{rank}(X)=\min(m,n))$ then you need $m \leq n$ to have $\mbox{rank}(X)=m$..

Comment: @BrianBorchers so you a saying the answer is complete. Just $X$  should have the rank of $m$ and at the same time this means $m \leq n$, and I should ask another question on impact of rank $m$ on singular values of the matrix $X$. Right?

Comment: @GoodLuck Yes, the answer is complete.

Comment: OK, can you say anything perhaps on singular values for $X$ and a bit of condition of $m \gt n$, I know it is extra demand but that will help me, or better should I ask another question...